# Mailchimp and Google sheets integration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, mailchimp, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to  to integrate mail chimp list with google sheets such that every time a member is added to a list it should fill in email address, first name and last name of the member automatically into a google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible if you deploy your script as a web app and use its URL as a webhook endpoint in Mailchimp. See links below to **official documentation**.

- [Read the Apps Script documentation about Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Read Mailchimp's API documentation about Webhooks](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/about-webhooks/)

Comment: You should do more in an answer than just link documentation. If that's all that can be done for a question, comment and vote to close as it is a poorly researched question.

Comment: @tehhowch I think the answer is sufficient. Half the time folks just don't know where to look to find the answers they need. I specifically referenced documentation I myself used to solve this very same issue. I thought it better to give the OP the tools to solve the problem for himself rather than just hand him code I've written. You are however free to disagree with my assessment.

Comment: @DimuDesigns Hey thank you for that info. It was helpful, but i wanted to ask if you had worked on the same thing?

Comment: @DimuDesigns I agree on leaving things for the OP to learn from rather than providing a turn-key solution. If those links stop working though, your current answer doesn't offer much for future readers.

Comment: @HarshaPatil unlikely. You have been given the gist of the solution and very appropriate reference documentation for what you seek. If you have a **specific** question relating to your implementation of the feature you want, ask a new question related specifically to that. If you want someone to do it all for you, then pay someone to do it all for you.

Comment: @HarshaPatil And deny you the opportunity to learn for yourself? I would never be so cruel ;)